# Handling all clients in a java Socket Server

Tags: android, sockets

I have a server and i am trying to send to all clients a specific input(string). My code is here:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            while (true) 
                {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    mClients.add(client);                        
                    boolean finished = false;
                    try                             
                        {
                        for (int i=0; i<mClients.size(); i++) 
                        {
                            Socket well = mClients.get(i);
                            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(well.getInputStream());
                            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(well.getOutputStream());                                
                            // Print a message:
                            System.out.println("Client from : " + client.getInetAddress() + " port " + client.getPort());
                            // now get the input from the socket...                  

                                while(!finished) 
                                {
                                    String st = in.readLine();
                                    // Send the same back to client
                                    out.println(st);
                                    // Write it to the screen as well
                                    System.out.println(st);
                                    // If the input was "quit" then exit...
                                    if (st.equals("quit")) { finished = true; System.out.println("Thread exiting..."); }
                                }
                        }
```

As it seems i am doing something wrong. Anyway i am trying to store all the connected sockets to a vector and then send them the string received by one of them. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

In the first while(true) statement, only listen for incoming connections and then create a separate thread to handle that client connection.

From there, you could add each outPutStream you create, within each thread, into an global ArrayList. Loop through the arrayList(create a method for this with a String Parameter) and write whatever message you want to within said method.

Check out this [Oracle Tutorial on Socket Communication](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) for help